# Unable to access the response variable in RSpec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this in my gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~>3.0' 
  gem 'rspec-its'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'json_spec'
  gem "rspec_json_schema_matcher"
  gem 'faker'
end
```

i have this request spec in `spec/request/posts/show_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rspec/its'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe 'GET /posts/:id', :type => :request do

  let(:user) {create(:user)}
  let(:guest) {create(:user, :as_guest)}
  let(:post) {create(:post)}
  let(:id) {post.id}

  before(:each) {get "/posts/#{id}"}

  context "when the post exists" do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end

  context 'when a post is not found with the ID' do
    let(:id) {-1}
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
  end

end
```

when i run `bundle exec rspec` I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `response' for #<Class:0x00000002016470> (NameError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `response` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). (RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError)

Change

```
context "when the post exists" do
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
end
```

to

```
context "when the post exists" do
  it 'status code is 200'
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```

Or, even shorter, seeing that you use `its`

```
context "when the post exists" do
  its(:response) { is_expected.to have_http_status(:success) }
end
```

PS: you get the error above when you run your code as a `controller` spec. For some reason running it with the `request` type throws the way less descriptive error that you are getting.

Comment: Does your `rails_helper` `require 'rspec/rails'` ?

Comment: Yes my `rails_helper` does require `rspec/rails`

Answer (score 1):

Slightly piggybacking off the comments of the answer, but I have had these  issues each time setting up a new environment. Even so, **I have a list of rules I follow to track down such issues**.

*Here are the 3 things to check for when making sure you are getting the proper helpers for your tests:*

1. If you are using the `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` option to omit the need for the *type metadata*, make sure that your [folder names are named or pluralized correctly](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure), and that your spec files are in the correct folder for the functionality you wish to access.
2. If the problem exists where your have your spec in the correct folder, or if you are using the *type metadata* in your top-most describe block, you are missing a required module somewhere (like the OP missing the 'rspec/rails' in their rails_helper). Double check your rails/spec_helper files, and make sure that the rails_helper is being requires in your **.rspec file** or **spec file**.
3. Lastly, if you are missing functionality that comes from an included module that needs more than a require and that you see has been included, make sure that it is set to the correct spec type. **e.g. Devise test modules that have the option to set the type (type: :controller)**

   a. If this is the case and you need one of these **type-based includes** to cover more than one spec type, include it again with the 2nd type set to its type, or remove the type entirely if you don't care about your test speeds.

I hope that helps someone figure out issues in the future.